# Get Data from DB without refreshing the page gives 500 internal server error when i ketp the refresh rate to 0.01sec

Tags: javascript, php

I have code to get the page by refreshing the part of the code instead of whole page. It works fine.

But when I change the refresh interval from 1 sec to 0.01 sec to get an instant response, the whole site kinda crashes.

While checking the error log i came to know that it is due to the cartcount.php page.

**Index:**

```
<div class="font-size-50" id="cartcount"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function(){
      $('#cartcount').load('cartcount.php?id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>');
             refresh();
      });
      function refresh()
        {
           setTimeout( function() {
              $('#cartcount').load('cartcount.php?id=<?php echo $u_id; ?>');
                   refresh();
        }, 10);
     }
</script>
```

**Cartcount.php**

```
<?php include("db.php"); 
 
$u_id = $_GET["id"];

    $sqlstep30 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM cart WHERE u_id = '$u_id'";
    $rowNumstep30 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlstep30);
    $countstep30 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowNumstep30);           
    
    echo $countstep30["total"];
?>
```

Please help me understand why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: Go check the error log, that is _always_ the first thing to do, when you get a 500 and the reason is not immediately clear. Your server probably gets overloaded, because it gets hammered with requests in such a nonsensically short interval.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Can you suggest any update on the code to request the data instantaneously at the same time not to put such pressure on the server..

Comment: Why would this need constant refreshing to begin with? The cart content changes based on user interaction on your site, yes? Then any updates should probably be triggered by that functionality, and not just get polled constantly.

Answer (score 0):

An AJAX call every 0.01 second is very bad idea and it will stress out your server when you have multiple visitors. You already asking for new data even when the previous request probably didn't finished.

If possible you can maybe better use `Server-Sent Events` https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp your server will send data when the server is ready to send it. And if you want real time data you can better use web sockets.

And then the question, why on earth you want to update your cart every 0.01 second?

And your query is not safe... use mysqli prepared statements or pdo to prevent SQL injection!

Comment: Hi , thanks for the response. so, the reason why I want to update my cart instantaneous is so that users can see the change in cart count number that they will see on cart icon of website when they click on add to cart button. Here I m using jquery for data insert without refresh of page for add to cart, so I would like to see the change in number instant once any product added to cart.

Comment: You dont need extra ajax calls for that, why dont you return that number while some one click on add to cart and store that number in a session or localstorage. Or add that number with javascript after the add to cart function finished